# NULL value on Round and avg

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get an avg time which has some null value

```
(ROUND (AVG (TRUNC (starttime- endtime)*24 + TRUNC (24 * MOD (endtime- starttime, 1)))))
```

I am getting below output

```
48
22
15
96
22
(NULL)
52
```

is there any way I can pass '-' value manually wherever the null us appearing

Comment: Is that only a **display** issue, or are you actually planning to use a dash along with numeric values in further processing? If it's only for displaying (on a report, for example), the correct way to do this is not in SQL, but in your front-end software. Pretty much all front-end programs allow you to display NULL as blank space, or as `(NULL)` as you are seeing it, or as `-`, or in any other way you desire. For more help, tell us what front-end you are using (SQL\*Plus? SQL Developer? Toad? etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IS NULL` along with a `CASE` expression to conditionally display `-` for `NULL` calculations:

```
SELECT
...
    CASE WHEN starttime - endtime IS NOT NULL
         THEN TO_CHAR(ROUND(AVG(TRUNC(starttime-endtime)*24 + TRUNC(24*MOD(endtime-starttime, 1)))))
         ELSE '-' END AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use the `COALESCE` function as follows:

```
COALESCE(
    TO_CHAR((ROUND(
        AVG(TRUNC(STARTTIME - ENDTIME) * 24 + TRUNC(24 * MOD(
            ENDTIME - STARTTIME,
            1
        )))
    ))),
    '-'
)
```

Please note that `TO_CHAR` is used as '-' and result of `AVG` function needs to be of the same data type

Answer (score 1):

In almost all cases, this is a **display** issue which should be addressed in your front-end program, not in the query itself.

For illustration, here is how the output looks like in SQL*Plus: first with the default (which is for `null` to be shown as an empty field, "white space"), then after I use the SQL*Plus command `set null` (which has **nothing to do** with SQL, it is strictly an SQL*Plus command!) to show `null` as `(NULL)` (as you have it right now) and then as `-` as you requested. Note that there are absolutely no changes to the query; all the changes are SQL*Plus setting changes, the database itself doesn't know anything about these changes.

```
SQL> select ename, comm from scott.emp where deptno = 30;

ENAME        COMM
---------- ----------
ALLEN         300
WARD          500
MARTIN       1400
BLAKE
TURNER          0
JAMES

6 rows selected.
```

Using the `set null` command:

```
SQL> set null '(NULL)'
SQL> select ename, comm from scott.emp where deptno = 30;

ENAME        COMM
---------- ----------
ALLEN         300
WARD          500
MARTIN       1400
BLAKE      (NULL)
TURNER          0
JAMES      (NULL)

6 rows selected.

SQL> set null '-'
SQL> select ename, comm from scott.emp where deptno = 30;

ENAME        COMM
---------- ----------
ALLEN         300
WARD          500
MARTIN       1400
BLAKE      -
TURNER          0
JAMES      -

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: thanks , i got it and worked on this method as well